# Dictionary.py too many values to unpack

Tags: python

Whenever I try to reload my dictionary.DB file, it keeps telling me:

```
too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

but there are 4 values I'm using `word, name, definition, wordtime`. Worktime is just `time.time()`. This is the def load code:

```
def load():
   dWord = {}
   for word in open("Dictionary.DB", "r").readlines():
      if len(word.strip()) >0:
         word, name, definition, wordtime = word.split()
         dWord[word] = name, definition, int(wordtime)
   Dictionary.dWord = dWord

# Adding words to DB
Dictionary.dWord[word] = user, definition, wordtime
```

Example:

```
{'dog': ('charles', 'a animal', 1387199008)}
```

And when printing `word.split()` this is result:

```
['dog', 'charles', 'a', 'animal', '1387199870']
```

Comment: What if there are spaces in, say, the definition?

Comment: It looks like you might be receiving too many values from your word.split() statement. more than 4

Comment: use `print word.split()` to see what you are getting and what you are expecting instead

Comment: Yeah there are spaces in the definition.

Comment: Even without spaces in the definition, your variables will probably not end up with the values you expect. In your example, the variable `name` would have the value `('name',`. You can't just write a dict to a file and read it back. Have a look into `json` or `pickle` to properly write a data structure to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
raw = word.split()
word, name, definition, wordtime = raw[0], raw[1], ' '.join(raw[2:-1]), raw[-1]
```

if you are sure spaces only appear in `definition`

This works for longer different number of spaces:

```
word = 'dog charles a cute cute animal 1387199870'
# definition -> 'a cute cute animal'
```

Comment: Yeah only spaces are in definitions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the line:

```
word, name, definition, wordtime = word.split()
```

is the problem. Check what **word.split()** is returning. According the error your posted, it must be returning more than four values. Perhaps some empty string.

Comment: Uh how would I get the bot to print the word.split() without it erroring though?

Comment: The error is because you are trying to put the result of word.split() in to word, name, definition and wordtime. And those are four values. just add print(word.split()) before that line in order to send to output the result of word.split() or use a debugger ;)

Comment: ['dog', 'charles', 'a', 'animal', '1387199870']

Comment: It took the space away and made into two words. 'a', 'animal' is suppose to be 'a animal'

Comment: Well ... Then you already know what the problem is. I recommend you save things like "a animal" in the form "a_animal" or something like that. Then you can split it again using "_" as separator. Ah, is my answer help you, don't forget up vote me and check it as solved. ;)